# Alexa custom skill audio directive resume previous music playback

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit

I am writing a simple skill that plays some MP3 files when launched. I have this working but if there was some music playback previously on the echo device it does not resume after my skill has finished. How do I resume my previous music session (play back from Spotify if that is relevant) Here is the relevant part of my code

```
    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        logger.info("In Noise handler")
        
        url = random.choice(noises_urls)
        
        handler_input.response_builder.add_directive(
            PlayDirective(
                play_behavior=PlayBehavior.REPLACE_ALL,
                audio_item=AudioItem(
                    stream=Stream(
                        token=url,
                        url=url,
                        offset_in_milliseconds=0,
                        expected_previous_token=None),
                    metadata=None
                )
            )
        ).set_should_end_session(True)
        
        return handler_input.response_builder.response
```

I have tried changing Play behaviour to REPLACE_ENQUEUED and ENQUEUE but these does not play my audio file immediately.

Comment: If I got it right, you want to be able to resume the mp3 in your skill where it stopped for the next time you launch the skill right?

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want to be able to resume the audio where you left it. You can do this adding the AMAZON.ResumeIntent, more information can be found here:

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html#intents

Also there is an audio player sample using python in the Alexa GitHub repository that includes the AMAZON.ResumeIntent for your reference:

https://github.com/alexa-samples/skill-sample-python-audio-player